# How to make a circular array using offset object as center?

Tags: modifiers

We know that the there is an **Object Offset** option for **Array** modifier, but when trying to make a circular array with that offset object as the center of the array circle, it always doesn't behave quite like what's expected. So how to make a nice and controllable circular array?

**P.S.**: There is an old [trick on CGCookie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5teWMHUDgs/) about moving the object's origin. I wonder if there is any way to do this without changing the location of the origin. :)

[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to move the origin? Of course it is possible, you just have to calculate the rotation and translation of the empty manually. Not hard with a little bit of trigonometry but generally unnecessary.

Comment: Since the original origin will be taken in further use. And it is not so easy to calculate it back unless it fits any item listed in the **SHIFT CTRL ALT C** menu.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: The link on CGCookie seems to be gone. I couldn't find it but would love to see the other option as well if you can relink? Thanks!

Comment: @fabriced Oh right, it does outdated. Luckily I tried to find the video on YouTube. Please recheck the updated link.

Comment: CGCookies video link can be accessed via internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20171108061123/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5teWMHUDgs&gl=US&hl=en

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Add an empty at the origin of the object that you want to duplicate. 
(Remember to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and select rotate and scale, to [apply transormations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation) on the original object).
Then, add an array modifier with object offset linked to this empty.

Set the 3D cursor to the desired centre of the circle. Add another empty here. Make it the parent of the other empty. Now select only the centre empty. Rotate.
The amount of rotation is of course dependent on the number of objects, e.g. 12 objects = 30°.

If you want the single elements to "touch" as in your picture you need to either adjust the object width or the radius. The circumference of the circle is 2 * PI * radius, so the width has to be the n<sup>th</sup> (e.g. 12) part of it. (Or, if it is not about absolute exactness, it can be done visually.)

[image: Screenshot]

You probably want to parent the object to the centre empty.

This circle is "controllable" as you can simply change the angle by rotating the centre empty.

Comment: Hi his, I just updated my question with more detail. Could you please take a further look at it? Thanks.

Comment: This makes sense to me. I just wonder what if the cube already got a parent before that, in that case, you have to clear the old one and parent it to the center empty (then parent back again?). But your idea is indeed what I mean by "controllable".

Comment: The cube would be the parent, the centre empty its child, and the outer empty the child of the centre empty. So no problem there.

Comment: Good point. Yeah, I think this solves all concerning problems. By the way, I bet the **Pivot** constraint can be used instead, similarly. So it seems plenty of ways in doing so. If you think the Pivot constraint works as well, please consider complementing that in your answer to guide other guys better. :)

Comment: Probably. But that constraint is marked with "very buggy", even in the GUI. I would refrain from using it yet for productive work.

Comment: Life saver! I was going crazy!!!!

Comment: This is super tricky. Great answers, but here are more details: (0) new scene (1) Move the cube to the left (2) make an empty at the inner edge of the cube (call it "Cube empty") (3) add an empty in the middle of the scene/array (call it "scene empty") (4) apply Rotation and scale to all (ctrl + a > Rotation and scale) (5) click the scene empty and in its "Object" modifier pane, parent it to "Cube empty" (6) add Array modifier to the cube (say, 12 count, then tick "object offset > select Scene empty") (7) from the top view, rotate the Cube empty (8) move cube or count nb to adjust the array.

Comment: I struggled to realize that for a rotational array, the reference object needed to have the same origin as the model I wanted spun, and the reference object/empty is what needed to have a rotation. Splitting the part of the mesh I wanted spin into a new object, spinning it with array and an empty-object reference, (uv mapping it before applying the array), and then rejoining the mesh together worked :bow:

Comment: I couldn't get this to rotate about the centre point. Then I realised i still had "Relative Offset" turned on. So if you're having trouble, make sure you have relative offset turned off

Comment: Clearest explanation I've read. Thanks.

Answer (score 37):

Just want to complement with several tricks that I just figured out. They all share with the same idea - to offset the rotation pivot of the *Offset Object*:

**Variant 1**:

Using 3D Cursor as pivot. (PROS: Fast and straight forward. CONS: Not suitable for animation)

First, use an empty object in *Object Offset* section in the **Array** modifier setting, then, all you have to do is to rotate the empty object,  instead of the arrayed object itself:

[image]

[image]

**Variant 2**:

Using another object as rotate center.

Note that this variant uses two empties; one at the cube center (just like Variant 1) and one for the pivot point (replacing the 3D Cursor in Variant 1).

To do the actual rotation after setting the *Active Element* as Pivot Point, first <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> the empty at the cube center to select it, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right-Click</kbd> the pivot center empty to select that as well, then <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate.

[image]

**Variant 3**:

Parenting.

[image]

**Variant 4**:

Using *Pivot* constraint.

[image]

**Variant 5**:

Using *Hook* modifier and *Copy Location* constraint.

[image]

Comment: How do you "drag-multiply"? (First gif) looks neat

Comment: I just select the cube then hit R to rotate along current pivot (I've switched pivot type to 3D Cursor, as seen in the same gif).

Comment: This does not work. Can you add description how you did it? Gifs are telling nothing.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos They are very intuitve IMHO, or can you tell which one is puzzling you?

Comment: When I hit R I'm just rotating selected object (not making 9 copies of it).

Comment: I believe that's unlikely to happen if you follow every step I did for each variant. My two cents: choose proper pivot point; 2. select the proper object. Or you can share a screencast to show how to reproduce that. I really want to help you on this.

Comment: Your answer is not complete. It's not clear what you're doing from the beginning. What is the "offset object"? Are you using the array modifier? That's what @PawełAudionysos, me and others don't understand.

Comment: I wanted to do Variant 1 and, as @PawełAudionysos said, I can't make it work. The gifs alone are not very helpful.

Comment: @luis.parravicini I see. Please the updated answer.

Answer (score 11):

To do that, you would need the arrayed object's origin to be in the same location as your offset object's origin. Try this test:

1. Add a cube.
2. *In Edit mode* move that cube to the left. The cube's origin should remain unchanged and in the same location.
3. Return to Object mode and add an empty (hopefully you haven't moved your 3D Cursor, so the empty should have the same origin as your cube).
4. Rotate the empty (say... 5 degrees)
5. Add an Array modifier on the cube using the empty as your offset. You should see the circular array form around the empty.

Comment: Hi Fweeb, yep, it works.  :) But is there any way to avoid changing the location of the origin? I think that's I really meant, wait I should update the question, sorry for that.

Comment: If you want the arrayed object to keep its origin fixed, then you might be better off using Dupliverts instead of the array modifier. It's an older technique, but it *does* have the side benefit of being more memory efficient (Dupliverts uses instances whereas the array modifier generates geometry). Failing that, you could also try a path constraint (to a bezier circle) on a regular array with just a relative offset.

Comment: Sure Fweeb, I agree with the idea by using Dupliverts, and I know that way, too. I'm just thinking about using Array modifier, since it is much more flexible and controllable with less additional work, in case that I need to animate that.

Answer (score 6):

People have been struggling with Leon's answer. Here is how it works (I'm using default blender scene, with 3D Cursor placed at the origin):

1. Go to Top Ortho View (<kbd>Numpad7</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad5</kbd>).
2. Add an Empty (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Empty > Plain Axis). This empty will act as the center point.
3. Add a cube and move it 5 units in Y direction. (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Mesh > Cube, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
4. Move cube's origin to 3D Cursor. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, **Origin to 3D Cursor**).
5. Add Array modifier to the cube. Set number of copies to (say) 12 and turn off **Relative Offset** option.
6. Turn on Object Offset and choose empty from the drop-down list.
7. Make sure the cube is still selected, now press <kbd>R</kbd> and perform rotation. All the array elements will start following circular path around the empty. You can distribute them evenly by mouse or you can type an angle as you normally do in rotation.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I didn't change the object origin, since normally you don't want to do that, which is why I use tricks (like two empties) as workaround. But your way is good if it is not quite a matter. :) Plus, I've updated the answer sometime ago. I think it should make things clearer. Feel free to discuss.

Comment: Yeah that didn't work......

Answer (score 4):

There is a method that actually doesn't require an array modifier:

First figure out how many objects you need, then divide 360 by that number and you have the amount of degrees between each object. For this example, I use a step value of 10 degrees for 36 objects.

Then place the 3D-Cursor in the center of rotation and set the pivot point in the header to 3D-Cursor.

[image: pivot point in the 3D header]

Select your object, duplicate it with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and then without even confirming that hit <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

That way, Blender considers duplication and rotation as a single action, not two.

You can now use the repeat hotkey <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to create a full circle of objects and they will be rotated evenly around the cursor.

You can use <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to create linked copies instead of <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> if you want to save a bit of memory and filesize. All objects will then use the same mesh.

The advantage of this method is that you have ready to use objects which keep their axes and you save the time for setting up the modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I used blender once to create so called Venetian blinds with an array modifier. To keep rotation of the array objects around there individual origin, I rigged the object to use with the array modifier to a single bone in the center of the object. When you rotate this bone, each object created by the array modifier will rotate around it's own center.

Answer (score 0):

On recent versions of Blender (I'm using 3.0, the name of the node will change on earlier versions), it is possible to obtain a circular array, centered around the original object without creating any empty with `Geometry Nodes`.

First, add a Geometry Node modifier to your object:

[image]

Then go in the Geometry Nodes tab:

[image]

Finally, create (using Add/Search) the following nodes (if you don't care about the rotation of your object, you don't even need to specify the Rotation field):

[image]

You can then change the number of vertices and radius by changing the properties of the `Mesh circle`, or change the rotation by tweaking the `Align Euler to Vector`. The good thing is that you can also save this node and reuse it in multiple places without recreating this graph (in the modifier, simply choose the appropriate Geometry Node in the drop down). For instance, you can change the rotation this way:

[image]

**What's happening?**

Basically, the `Mesh Circle` creates a "circle" made of `N` segments centered on the current object. Then `Instance on Points` will copy the `Instance` (here our original object) on all the point contained in our Mesh Circle. What is trickier to understand is maybe the rotation. The diamond shape of the `Rotation` plug means that it is a [Field](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html), which means that it waits for a kind of Function (to provide a different rotation for each point). The red nodes (here `Normal`) are inputs of this function, and this function is evaluated for any point in `Points` (so basically, here we loop over the points in the circle, and for all of them we take the normal). The `Align Euler to Vector` part will return the appropriate rotation to ensure that the local `X/Y/Z` axis of the object (depending on what you choose on the first line) will point towards the `Vector` field, here the normal of each node.