# Can't make circle of objects using array modifier

Tags: modifiers

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  As you can see in the .blend file, my cylinders are super wonky and distorted.  Trying to get them all the same size and in a tight circle with 5 cylinders.

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/39103

Thanks

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31961/how-to-distribute-objects-in-a-circular-pattern-on-a-surface-radial-array-pola

Comment: Please expand on the question and make it so it stands on its own, independent of the linked file. Once the file disappears from pasteall.org this question will make no sense

Answer (score 1):

[image]Rather than using the empty as an offset on the array modifier, add a bezier circle the size of the circle you want and a curve modifier to the cylinder.  Select fit to curve and tweak the x offset until they fit.

Comment: Awesome that totally worked!  Thanks so much batFINGER