# How do I create four circular copies in edit mode?

Tags: modifiers

I am creating this simple windmill model for a tutorial:

[image]

I have created one blade. What is the most efficient method to create the other three spaced 90 degrees apart around the main shaft? Array modifiers only work in Object mode correct? I see two ways:

1. Create the blade as a separate object and in object mode use the array modifier.
2. Manually copy/paste 3 more versions of the blade and manually position each.

Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Array modifier will be harder to tune. Copy/Paste can be easy if you set your cursor as pivot point at the good location (and you can alt+D in object mode so that you can rework one blade to impact them all). Third possibility is to use duplifaces (but not so interesting as there is only 4 blades). Also you can spin the blade in edit mode.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center. I don't think Array is complex for this situation, it's just snapping cursor to somewhere around center of the tube and adding an empty.

Comment: Also - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31961/how-to-distribute-objects-in-a-circular-pattern-on-a-surface-radial-array-pola and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-use-array-to-create-circular-array-without-spiralling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the edit mode as you have made 1 blade and you want to. Set the 3d Cursor. Make duplicate Shift+D of the 1st part and do not move it and just press r and type 90 and the 2nd blade is set same way repeat for 3rd and 4th blade .
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to object mode, set the 3D cursor to the center of the shaft by selecting the shaft, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and set origin at center of mass. Then, hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and click cursor to selected. Now, go back to the blade, go in edit mode select everything. Set the Pivot point (button located next to 'Mode' and 'Material' buttons in the 3D view, and choose 3D cursor. Last, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate, hit <kbd>R</kbd> and then the axis it should go around, type 90 and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Then keep hitting <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to redo the that duplication until you have the right amount of blades.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to automate this would be with the 'Repeat Last' command, `SHIFT + R`

1. Select the faces and hit `SHIFT + D` to start the duplicate faces tool
2. Without doing anything else hit `R` to rotate them the desired amount manually or in this case just type `90` (you can see where you're typing in the upper left corner)
3. Hit `ENTER` to complete the command and you'll see the 'Add Duplicate' dialog box in the lower left. You can also change the angle in that dialog box now.
4. With the dialog box still up, hit `SHIFT + R` to redo the duplication + rotation as many times as necessary. You can even hold it down to repeat many times!