# Make all objects on an array fit exactly on a curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I created cube, then I created circle-curve and scaled it. Then I set modifers on the cube: array to fit the curve length, and next a curve modifier. But my cubes not fit exactly on the curve, and I don't know why :-/ If someone finds a solution to this problem, please share it.

I attached screenshots of my steps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center ?

Comment: @poor not related, because I want to create with curve, to make more complex shapes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Fit Curve changes the number of copies in the array to fit within the length of the curve object specified in Curve.  If the length of your mesh is a multiple of the length of the curve, then there will be an exact fit.  It is up to you to scale your mesh.

Comment: In fact the answer above its true but its somehow sad. The solution will be pretty easy for someone "python-experienced" imo ... I have the curve of an exact length and the object too and I want to repeat it 10x or 50x so the gap between copies could change but the copies could be the exact number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things.

With the current selection you are showing, pop open your transform panel (<kbd>N</kbd>), then in the X Dimension hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click+drag left.

Or if the curve size does not matter, select the curve and scale it up, while also holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: For me this is not a solution, because I want to have bigger precision over tis.

Comment: The point is, is that whatever calculation you need to make to adjust one of the objects in this way, that is what is going to get you there. It is calculate-able.