# What's the best way to make a long, hollow cylinder composed of filigree?

Tags: modeling, objects

I'd like to make a pen composed of wavy filigree, similar to overlapping vines with hollow spaces between the "vines." The overlapping of vines holds the cylindrical shape. How would we go about making that?

I am new to Blender and don't know what Tags to add to this question.

Here is an example of filigree used on a ring: 
[image: example of filigree]

Comment: My first thought is to create a flat curve with the design then extrude and the use a  Curve modifier with a circular target.Try one of the main "create a logo in blender" tutorials to get the initial flat curve design.

Comment: @rob How is the design made? Drawn with grease pencil? Drawn in Illustrator and imported? Make holes in a long slab and curve it? Not clear about the "design" aspect.

Comment: Google will get you many versions of the same tutorial topic, and the first one I followed so many years ago involved tracing an image in the background with Curve bezier objects and closing them, creating the pattern and then converting to mesh later after extrusion.

Comment: @CraigDJones This is helpful. If possible, I'll add to this page the links to the videos that directly address my question.

Comment: Create the base shape (it might be easier to draw it in a vector graphics program like inkscape or illustrator and export it as SVG, then import it into blender and give it some extrusion), then use a curve>circle and an array modifier in "fit  curve"  mode. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-use-array-to-create-circular-array-without-spiralling and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47717/make-all-objects-on-an-array-fit-exactly-on-a-curve

Answer (score 2):

Its not pretty but ...

Here I used the **Bezier curves** to make a basic design, you might be better off using a vector package like **Inkscape** and then importing your design.
Note that it is **Cyclic**, **2D**, **Extruded** and **Beveled**.
[image]

I then converted the **Curve into a Mesh** (not sure that step is strictly necessary) and then added an **Array modifier**.
[image]

Created a **Bezier Circle** and rotated it by 90 degrees on the X and scaled it by 4.
[image]

Then added a **Curve modifier** after the array and set it to the new Circle.
[image]

This all took minutes and is bit rough, but I hope it gives you some ideas.