# How can I avoid or clean distortion in curves imported from SVG?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to create an image of a board (wood, silver, or gold) that is carved with some ornamentation, e.g.

[image]

[image]

The purpose is to create an imaging that will later be cut with a laser machine.
Therefore I first create the image in SVG, using inkscape (laser machine accept only VG), than I import the SVG in to Blender.

In Blender I grab only the ouyline, pull it down and create a Face (i.e. the board) and I use the rest of the part to carve through the board

I tried 2 method of carving through the Board - Knife Project, and Boolean Difference.

The methods works well when working with more simple structures, e.g:
[image]

But than other structure gets distorted, like in the images above.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to do it than the methods above?
2. How can I avoid/or clean the distortion in the image?

Edit:

As explained in [How can I model Gothic style windows?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51792/how-can-i-model-gothic-style-windows/51904#51904) (credit to ardito comment)

You don't actually need to separate the board and than curved it, instead:

1. open the SVG in InkScape and change the image to be filled (instead of only stroke)
2. import the SVG to blender
3. select the important mash and do ALT C and turn it into a mash
4. now you can simply extrude it and create a 3D img with carved spaces.
   [image]

unfortunately it doesn't work on complicated image, such as this:
[image]

import the SVG version of this image cause blender to convert some of the colors: i.e. black becomes transparent and vice versa.

If I tried to use the boolean difference than blender crashes.

the knife project seems to work - it took about 10 minutes to complete, now I need to delete about 100 faces - but this sometime fails to delete the correct face.

Comment: I always use the first (see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51792/how-can-i-model-gothic-style-windows/51904#51904) , but you have to be sure to level all resulting vertices on Z. An example file  would help to understand what's not working.

Comment: If by "distortion" you mean what I think you mean, you may want to remesh your object. See the accepted answer to [this related question.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39565/text-on-a-balloon/39566)

Comment: Unfortunaly SO doesn't let me attach files other than images

Comment: I use curves in blender, and for holes I find the best way is in the curve object first. Adding a filled shape to the main closed filled shape cause it to be unfilled inside that smaller shape - and if you can work entirely in a single curve object in edit mode in 2d curve, then you will have less problems with working out the mesh later. I also use the extrude function in the curve panel with bevel and resolution as a curve before converting to mesh. Much better results than trying to use complicated mesh boolean.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [How can I model Gothic style windows?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51792/how-can-i-model-gothic-style-windows/51904#51904) (credit to ardito comment)

You don't actually need to separate the board and then curve it, instead:

1. open the SVG in InkScape and change the image to be filled (instead of only stroke)
2. import the SVG to blender
3. select the important mesh and do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and turn it into a mesh
4. now you can simply extrude it and create a 3D object with carved spaces.
   [image]

Note: if the curve is distorted then select it, in the Properties editor in the Object Data tab, on the right, find *Extrude* and increase it by 1.