# How to make an object go around another circular objects?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, workflow

I am making a sort of steampunk element and I want to have small bolts go around a cylinder. I'm not sure what would be the most precise and quick method to achieve something like that:

[image]

My current model:

[image]

p.s. Also preferably with out using a curve modifier)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use an ***Array Modifier*** with the ***constant offset*** enabled.
Add an *Empty* (it'll be your pivot point). Next select the object, enter *Edit Mode* and place it as fas from *Empty* as you like. Being in *Object Mode* apply transformations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and add an ***Array Modifier*** to the object. Check the ***Constant Offset*** and ***Object Offset*** checkboxes. Select *Empty* below the second one.
[image]

Now just rotate the *Empty* (in your case by 60 degrees).
[image]

Comment: I've found the related answer, which explains more precisely how to use this method. Please check it out: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center

Answer (score 6):

I made an addon that do just want you want by pressing a button,It is not stable though.

Here is the [Addon](https://github.com/emaema/procedural-dupli-spin/blob/master/procedural%20dupli%20spin).

Suppose I want to make this sphere go around this object.

[image: Scene]

Before you run the addon,you should align the view with your axis of rotation I do this by selecting the face that its normal facing the axis and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> and the cursor should be in the middle so by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> I set the cursor to the center of the face.I select the sphere and go to *Edit mode*.I then run the addon from the Tool panel and set the number of duplicates (It is better to set it 2 times because blender didn't get it the first time).

[image: GIF]

Answer (score 6):

Imho there are a couple of ways. One very basic way is using a circle with less vertices (one per object to place around the cylinder), parenting your little object to it (only one needed, clear all origins before), and enabling vertex duplication- with rotation, like

[image]

then you can scale **in edit mode** the circle enough to match the cylinder surface, at your taste.

[image]

which gets you

[image]