# splitting edges around a ring

Tags: modeling, edges

I am attempting to model the London eye and I have made an edge where there should be two. Is there an easy way to split my edges into faces the whole way round the ring?

[image]

Comment: u can make the edge a pipe and then from pipe u can have many faces

Answer (score 2):

Select your object and delete everything but one "segment". Then use one of [these ways](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center) to create a circular array of it.

Then editing just one segment will affect all others. It will also result in a lighter model, and future changes will be much easier.

To actually split the edge select it and then use <kbd>B</kbd>evel in edit mode. It depends on the topology of your mesh but from what I can see, it looks like it should do what you intend.

Comment: an array. of course. That was how I was going to do it originally. Anyway we live and learn. cheers mate how do I mark this as answered?

Comment: You are welcome. Just tick the checkmark below the arrows on the left.