# Problems with array modifier offsets

Tags: modeling, modifiers, transforms

I'm new to Blender, and my English is not so good, so please excuse me.

I've been trying to use the *Array* modifier using the offsets of an unscaled, unrotated empty object to create an array of objects around the empty, but it seems like if the object has transforms like scaling and rotating, I'll have to synchronize the empty's transforms with the object.

Otherwise the modified objects are going to be scaled and rotated to the last object as the empty is to the first object.

I'm wondering if there is another way to get such a circular array of objects without doing anything to the empty.

By the way, I don't know if once I applied rotations to the transforms of an object, there could still be a way to rotate them on the axis I was expecting.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you need something very specific, you should probably be applying the rotation and scaling to the original object. Otherwise you can also do it without an *Array* modifier, just simply duplicate the object and then rotate it about any arbitrary point in the 3D scene by using the *3D Cursor* as transformation pivot. You will also benefit from scene optimization of using instanced objects.

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center

Comment: Quoting @ideasman42:" A good rule of thumb is:
**Apply rotation and scale to your models unless you have a reason not to.**" Read through this related link: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally realized I've been clicking Apply All Transforms to Deltas and that's exactly where my problems are from.