# Edit multiple parts of tower mesh simultaneously

Tags: modeling

I am trying to edit the following mesh from a game:
[image: Tower]

I would like to know if it is possible to link the 30 buttresses and walls together so that if I edit one of them, I will edit the other 29 as well? I am aware of X mirroring but from what I have read, this only appears to allow editing of two parts of a mesh at once.

Alternatively, is it possible for me to delete all except one of the walls and buttresses then, once I've finished my editing to the two, copy-paste those vertices in a circle around the centre?

I am still learning Blender so if anyone who answers can give step-by-step instructions, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Delete all the buttresses but 1 with the wall section and use circular array, related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center

Comment: Look at the Array modifier: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5teWMHUDgs

Comment: Thanks! I just tried your suggestions and this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments above indicate, the best way to do what I wanted is to create a circular array.

What I did was:

1. Delete everything except one buttress and wall.
2. In object mode, select the remaining buttress and wall then in the Modifiers panel, click "Add Modifier" > "Array"
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > "Cursor to Centre" then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > "Empty" > "Plain Axes".
4. Reselect the buttress and wall then in the Modifiers panel, tick the "Add Offset" box, then click the box below that and select the empty created in the previous step, then untick the "Relative Offset" box and finally, change "Count" to the number of duplicates needed.
5. Reselect the created Empty then, in the transform box, change the Rotations until the clones are positioned correctly.
6. Make the required edits to the mesh.
7. When finished, in the Modifiers panel, click on "Apply".

Edit: The above are the instructions for Blender v2.49, which I was using at the time. For v2.79, the instructions are slightly different:

1. Delete everything except one buttress and wall.
2. In object mode, select the remaining buttress and wall then in the Modifiers panel (wrench button in Properties pane), click "Add Modifier" > "Array"
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > "Empty" > "Plain Axes".
4. Reselect the buttress and wall then in the Modifiers panel, tick the "Object Offset" box, then click the dropbox below that and select the empty created in the previous step, then untick the "Relative Offset" box and finally, change "Count" to the number of duplicates needed.
5. Reselect the created Empty then, in the transform box, change the Rotations until the clones are positioned correctly.
6. Make the required edits to the mesh.
7. When finished, in the Modifiers panel, click on "Apply".