# Help with modelling rocket fin

Tags: modeling, extrude

I'm trying to model a simple rocket but got stuck at the fins.
I've made the rocket body, then proceeded to extract two faces from the place I want the fins to be attached to and converted the faces to a path. There's another path that show the path I want the fin to follow, like in the following picture:

[image: current rocket model]

The problem is that when I select the fin guide and select the fin profile as bevel target, I get:

[image: wrong fin]

What I was expecting is that the fin begin at the path selected in the first image, and be face to face with the rocket body, something like in this 2d sketch:

[image: desired result]

How do I achieve what I want?

[image]

Comment: Could you post some reference image of what you want to achieve? Or just draw the shape on screenshot.

Comment: @LukeD I've edited the question with a 2d sketch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would do this with simple mesh modeling.

Start with one vertex and **Extrude** it to create faces. **F2** add-on (bundled with Blender) could be your friend here.

After making the shape you will need to snap it to selected edge on Rocket body.

[image: mesh]

At the end you can use this method: [How to make a circular array using offset object as center?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center) to position your fins and add **Solidify** modifier.

[image: final]

Comment: Any particular reason to not start extruding from the rocket body instead? Seens a bit easier than your solution

Comment: @Vitor Two reasons to be exact. First - there is only one edge on rocket body, second - starting from sharp point is easier to maintain final quad based topology.