# Polar Array + imported Rhino Geometry

Tags: modeling, modifiers

***Blender No0b***

I imported some geometry from Rhino into Blender via .FBX which I would like to animate.

I can't however seem to get the array modifier to work. After playing around with it I can get a relative offset;

[image]

but no 'polar array'

[image]

Hope its something simple due to me not knowing blender so good, but is it an issue with the imported geometry?

Thanks! much appreciation.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this?: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLGYsd4lEjY&t=151s good for circular arrays