# How to place columns in a circle?

Tags: modifiers

#### My goal

I want to create a radial array of columns like in this screenshot:

[image]

#### Tutorial that I am following

[Blender 2.8 Array Modifier Rotate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6m5r7Uq-Khg) video on YouTube.

#### My steps

1. I've create a single column object:

[image]

2. I've create a plain axis:

[image]

3. Added «*Array*» modifier to the column:

[image]

4. Set «*Relative Offset*» to `(0, 0, 0)`:

[image]

5. But when I set «*Object Offset*» around the plain axis, I get this:

[image]

What I do wrong? I can not understand what I missed.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, thank you very much. It helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply scale. Press Ctrl+A. Apply scale

Now select the empty and rotate

[image]