# How to rotate direction of empty plain axes

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to make a lighthouse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlqvf0cPk9c&t=487s

I am stuck on a part where I have created a support geometry (the curvy triangle in the screenshot), and want to duplicate the support to go around the lighthouse geometry I created. In the tutorial, it says to center the origin to the middle of the lighthouse, and then use an empty plain axes and array modifier to duplicate the support. The video also says to rotate & scale the railing object. I did all these things, but I believe something went wrong along the way because after increasing the count on my array modifier, nothing happened.

My hunch is that my plain axes is not oriented properly. In the screenshot below, you'll see that the plain axes is centered around the origin I set, but it rotates vertically instead of horizontally (along the lighthouse's platform). I'd appreciate any leads on how to fix this. Thanks so much!
[image: Screenshot of lighthouse & support objects]

Comment: You're on the right thought path :) Try creating your empty again but ensure you have the "align" property set to "World" then when you rotate it to manipulate the array, make sure you rotate around the Z axis only.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center