# What is the easiest way to curve a cuboid?

Tags: modeling, transforms

I am trying to make a model of Richard Hammond's crash helmet from The Great Escapists, but I need to slightly curve a cuboid around both sides. this is what I am trying to create:

and the blender model currently:
[image: Side]
[image: front]
[image: Crash Helmet]

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't deleting a few faces from a *Mirrored*, *Solidified*, *Subdivided* hemisphere, or half round-cube, make an easier starting point than caving in the front of a full sphere?

[image]

Then duplicate some faces to new objects, and *Solidify* those the other way..

[image]

You can always randomise it later, maybe sculpt with a cloth brush..

Answer (score 2):

First off, amazing photo! :) But to give you some direction...

A very simple way to achieve this is to create some planes around your sphere, shrinkwrap them to your sphere, then add some thickness. Let me explain...

Begin with a plane, scale it to the correct size and be sure to apply the scale (<kbd>CTRL-A -> Scale</kbd>)
I have used an array modifier with an empty as the offset object to get the rotation, this is a simple technique, see here:
[How to make a circular array using offset object as center?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center)

[image]

Next, you'll need some geometry to work with, so add a Subdivision Surface modifier and set it to Simple

[image]

Then, use the Shrinkwrap modifier to tell the planes to "wrap" onto the surface of your sphere, set up like this:

[image]

Finally, add some thickness to your planes with a Solidify modifier

[image]

You should be able to adapt this technique and play with the settings to get your desired result.
Happy Blending! :)