# Link vertex's in single object

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Have created a wheel and want to move vertex's inside the wheel.
There are five holes and each hole has 266 vertex.
When changing/moving any vertex from any hole the other four vertex's from the other four holes must also change/move in the same direction.

### Have tried to use Vertex Group, (to create 266 groups is asking a bit to much)

Looking for a way/scrip/method like Alt+D that can linked those vertex's inside a object and manipulate one vertex (big arrow) will manipulate the four vertex`s (small arrows) the same way.
[image: wheel]

Comment: Hello :). Your best bet is to use Array modifier around a rotated empty. Model just one spoke, and others will be mirrored.

Comment: Related: [How to make a circular array using offset object as center?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6023/78972)

Comment: Another option, if the wheel can't be completely symmetrical, might be to cut the holes out with a single object that has the array modifier and make your changes to the cutting object.  @Jachyms solution is better though.