# Easy way to add multiple flower petals on this mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, mirror-modifier

So I was following this tutorial on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGLK1j9lE9Y

I noticed he used the array modifier to make the petals wrap around the center and I was wondering if this was possible but with my mesh:

[image]

[image]

I could just individually align the petals but I just want to know if theres a quicker way

Comment: Hope this help. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6025/142633

Answer (score 8):

Just for fun:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> dial up a 12-sided, fan-filled circle
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> split all faces by edges
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel all vertices, with 'clamp overlap' checked

[image]

**Edit:** ... (I didn't think anyone was going to take this one seriously, it's a bit 'niche' :D) .. This method produces duplicate vertices at the bevel-extremes. To get rid of those, and still have separate petals, follow up with:

- <kbd>M</kbd> merge all by distance
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> split all faces by edges, again.

Play with the bevel settings to see the various effects. These are the ones illustrated:

[image]

- Not a bad idea to have an even number of segments; it makes *Grid Fill* possible, later, if you want it, and subdivides better.
- 'Shape': 0.5 for a circular arc.
- 'Clamp Overlap' means you can drag the bevel to its limit. (see above for removing the resulting touching vertices)
- 'Superellipse' is the default setting, varying from a circular arc to positive/negative elliptical arcs, according to 'Shape', above.

Comment: That's so fast!

Comment: lmao thats pretty neat

Comment: How do you add the cuts? Control R doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Murth  Where do you want cuts?

Comment: The 12 cuts for the petals @RobinBetts

Comment: When I add the bevel modifier the cuts arent there the "pizza slices" in your video you sent @RobinBetts

Comment: @Murth sorry for late reply.. it was bed-time when I last commented.. When you call up a mesh > circle, there's an option in its creation panel: 'Triangle Fan'. That should give you the spokes.. or maybe I'm misunderstanding..

Comment: @RobinBetts Awesome thank you thats exactly what i was looking for, what do your bevel modifier settings look like to get that perfect round shape?

Comment: @Murth see further edit.

Answer (score 3):

Choose *Transform Pivot Point > 3D Cursor* and put the 3D cursor at the center of the flower:

[image]

Edit: As recommended by John, select the petal, type <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>30</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to duplicate and rotate, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to repeat:

[image]

Comment: I'd use Shift-D R30 Enter, then hit Shift-R 11 times to create the rest of the petals.

Comment: Oh you're right I tried Shift R and failed but it works your way

Comment: That's because Shift-R only works for the last operation. By usnig Enter after Shift-D and before the rotation, you're breaking the operation into two parts.

Comment: Yes but I thought the duplication would be lost by the rotation, I didn't know you could cumulate  ;)

Comment: 'Learn one useless fact every day' is my motto! :^)

Comment: You mean useful? I'm learning every day with Blender, I don't even know if any one can know the full software